# Is there a maximum to the amount of health/HP?

Tags: candy-box-2

I had accumulated a large quantity of candy and figured that since I had nothing else to spend them on at the time, I would eat them to increase my health. However my HP did not change as seen below. (I’m not playing in hard mode.)

Is there a hard limit to the amount of health you can have from eating candies? (I couldn’t find anything about it in the wiki.) Could it be a bug?

---

[image: Before and after screenshot of eating 11 million candies with no change to HP]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no maximum max health set by the game, but the maximum you can get out of eating candies is 900 (the function on row 4 in the code below maxes out at 900). You need to eat about 2 700 000 candies to reach the cap. Any candies eaten after that do not matter at all.

You can get much higher by using

> *pains au chocolat* in the Wishing Well to get more max health. (`gameGiftHealth` in the code below)

That method goes all the way to the max integer of javascript as it is defined in the script (9 007 199 254 740 992).

```
    var maxHp = 100;

    if (Saving.loadString("gameGameMode") != "hard") {
        maxHp += Math.ceil((1 - Math.exp(-this.game.getCandiesEaten().getCurrent() / 3000)) * 100) + Math.ceil((1 - Math.exp(-this.game.getCandiesEaten().getCurrent() / 400000)) * 800);
    }

    if (Saving.loadBool("gridItemPossessedHeartPendant"))
        maxHp += 300;

    if (Saving.loadBool("gridItemPossessedHeartPlug"))
        maxHp = Math.ceil(maxHp * 1.2);

    if (Saving.loadNumber("gameGiftHealth") > 0) {
        maxHp = maxHp + maxHp * (Saving.loadNumber("gameGiftHealth") / 5);
    }
```

Comment: Additionally, you can just beat the game and then you get infinite resources :D

Comment: Ah okay; thanks. (Iirc, CB1 had no such limit. This makes completing CB2 harder, but then this one seemed to be easier overall, so it’s not as much of a problem.)